# Git revert remote branch to previous commit

Tags: git, version-control, rollback

I made multiple commits to a branch to a branch and pushed them to a remote repo. There have been some merge commits in the middle as well. I wish to reset the branch to a known commit before all of these. And I do not wish to rewrite history on the remote.

Basically, I have the commits:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
F -> G -> H /
```

and I want to make a commit `E -> I` that just directly puts the branch in the same state as `A`. I do not care about reverting individual commits, not least because some of them are merge commits as well.

If it helps, think of this like rolling back a flawed deployment. I do not know and I do not care which individual commits are an issue. I just want to go back to the last known good version.

If it matters, `A` might be a merge commit as well.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764288/git-reset-to-previous-commit) but it was about rewriting history. The branch has already been pulled by others so I do not want to mess it all up for everyone.

Comment: As a side comment, the arrows should be pointing in the opposite direction. In git, children commits _point to_ their parents, not the other way around. I understand what you meant from reading the question but I could just as easily understood `E` to be the parent of all the other commits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `git reset` with `soft`

Start from A to get the state you want

```
git reset --hard <Commit A>
```

move to E without changing files

```
git reset --soft <Commit E>
```

then commit it

```
git add . && git commit -m "Commit I"
```

Comment: Huh. Wow. That makes sense. I didn't think of ever using reset in the other direction. Thanks a lot

Comment: Upvoted. I would be careful about the first `git reset --hard`. If you are not careful, you could end up moving _the branch_ and then you might have to do additional work to know what `E` was before (not particularly difficult.... just a little more work). It can be avoided by doing a simple checkout: `git checkout A; git reset --soft E; git checkout the-branch-on-E-if-you-are-using-one; git commit -m "Taking it back to how A was"`.

Comment: @eftshift0 thanks for the warning. It wouldn't be a concern for me in this case though, as the branch was already pushed upstream (hence all the problems) and therefore, I would have the remote branch still pointing to E.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using the kind-of new `git restore`:

```
git checkout E
git restore --worktree --staged --source=A .
git commit -m "A commit right after E that takes the project back to what it was like in A"
```