# git: how to revert to a previous commit and continue from there?

Tags: git, git-head

**[git newbie here]**

I have the following commits:

```
[c1]-->[c2]-->[c3]-->[c4]-->[c5]
```

HEAD is now at `c5` but I realized that `c4` and `c5` are not good and I wish to continue from `c3`. In other words, I wish to revert to `c3` mark it as HEAD and continue from this point on (make changes form this point). How can I do that?

when I get the commit of `c3`

```
$git checkout c3
```

improve some files and:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'lets continue from c3'
git push
```

it says:

```
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

Comment: You can use `git reset` for that.

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl thank you. can you be more specific, where do I use it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766177/10875738

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

then you get a file open with 2 msg " pick idCommit commit msg" => delete the 2 msg of the unused commit